# Creating contours from partial data set

Tags: qgis, point, contour

Is it possible to create contour lines based on part of the points and not the entire dataset?

Comment: Export the points to a new shapefile or have them selected while running the function (the latter might only work in Arcgis, not sure on Qgis)

Comment: @martin, thanks.
I copied part of the sata to a new layer and tried creating contours, but it did't work. It's a very very small area (few sq. meters) and very large differences (several 100s) between the value of each point (being the concentration of a contaminenet).
Is it possible to draw by hand a line between the point?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but if there's such a big change in a short distance it might be hard to visualize with contour lines. I would recommend that you rasterize the values using some interpolation method instead.